# Failed to open file :No such file or directory in android webview

Tags: java, android, webview

working android webview i got it i have tried many solutions unable to resolve

```
  E/ech.androidproject: Failed to open file '/data/data/tech.androidproject/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/snapshot_blob_32.bin': No such file or directory
    E/ech.androidproject: Failed to open file '/data/data/tech.androidproject/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin': No such file or directory
    E/ech.androidproject: Failed to open file '/data/data/tech.androidproject/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/icudtl.dat': No such file or directory
    E/ech.androidproject: Failed to open file '/data/data/tech.androidproject/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/chrome_100_percent.pak': No such file or directory
    E/ech.androidproject: Failed to open file '/data/data/tech.androidproject/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/stored-locales/en-GB.pak': No such file or directory
    E/ech.androidproject: Failed to open file '/data/data/tech.androidproject/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/stored-locales/en-GB.pak': No such file or directory
    E/ech.androidproject: Failed to open file '/data/data/tech.androidproject/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/stored-locales/en-GB.pak': No such file or directory
    E/ech.androidproject: Failed to open file '/data/data/tech.androidproject/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/resources.pak': No such file or directory
    E/ech.androidproject: Failed to open file '/data/data/tech.androidproject/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/stored-locales/en-GB.pak': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you solve it ?

Comment: no sir  not solved

Answer (score 2):

Go setting and clear all your data of your app, and reinstall it through android studio.

This helped me, I hope it'll solve your problem too.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

it was happening the same to me and i solved it adding a permission on the AndroidManifest.xml

**Add this permission:** `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

A little bit late but hope it helps!

Comment: Wait, what?
Adding an "internet permission" resolves the problem of not finding a directory?
I guess you solved it somewhere in your code but you didn't know.
Cuz internet permission has nothing to do with a local file.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHasanato the original post was asking about a webview which implies using the internet

Comment: @AP Oh, sorry about that, I didn't pay attention. Thanks for clarifying.